# AJAX return response is 0 and status is 4 on local call

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to implement a website that calls a local php file via XMLHttpRequest to get json data back.  The login function is being called from an HTML form. The file /var/www/picnit/api/member.api does exist and has sufficient privileges and has been tested using Chrome's Postman app.

```
//URL for member functions
var memberurl='/picnit/api/member.php';

//Request to be sent to the middleware
var request;

function login() {
    //Get and validate user inputs
    var username = $("input#Username").val();
    var password = $("input#Password").val();
    //Validation code omitted

    //Getting here means that the inputs validated

    //Request to be sent to the middleware
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //Create function that handles response
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        //Make sure request is ready, we only care about when done
        if(request.readyState === 4) {
            //Good data, proceed to login
            if(request.status === 200) {
                alert('200');
            }

            //Invalid username/password combo
            else if(request.status === 204) {
                alert('204');
            }

            //Our request messed up
            else if(request.status === 400) {
                alert('400');
            }

            //Something else went wrong
            else {
                alert('Unknown error: ' + request.status);
            }
        }
    };

    //Open request
    request.open('POST', memberurl, true);

    //Send request
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var parms = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
    request.send(parms);

    return false;
}
```

This always returns an alert with "Unknown error: 0" and I can not figure out why.  I don't think it can be cross domain as it's on the same server (an AWS EC2 instance).  And I'm not entirely sure on what Same Domain Policy is...

I've been searching other post here and have not found an answer yet. Thank you for your help in advanced.

Comment: Are you opening this page from `http://localhost/` or `file:///var/www/`?